# Angular2: How to prevent/ nullify history manipulation while implementing routerCanDeactivate?

Tags: javascript, angular

`routerCanDeactivate()` successfully prevents navigation away from component.

```
routerCanDeactivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction) 
  {
    return confirm("Do you want to discard unsaved changes ?");
  }
```

But if navigation is caused by Browser's `back` button or any other `history.back()` trigger,

then it doesn't keep the history intact and triggers `popState` on every trigger and eventually navigates to Browser's homepage (tested on Chrome).

---

**EDIT:**

I saved current component's URL in a variable `currentLocation` and

tried to manipulate `history` with `history api` but

just couldn't figure out the right order of api calls required to keep it intact.

```
routerCanDeactivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    history.replaceState(null,null, this.currentLocation);
    history.forward();
    return confirm("Do you want to discard unsaved changes ?");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to `window.onpopstate` triggering at every back button click,

I thought that a `pushState` will be required. But that wasn't the case, and following code works perfectly.

```
routerCanDeactivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    if(confirm("Do you want to discard unsaved changes ?")){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      history.forward();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

But it would be nice if somebody could explain what is happening because I don't have much knowledge of `history api`.