# Angular2. How to prevent route change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a child component in angular 2 which handles all routes after a certain level, the route is defined as this in the parent component

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/*other', name: 'Detail', component: DetailsViewComponent, useAsDefault: true },
])
```

Now, in the details view I want to make sure the URL entered is valid and if not prevent the change.

Using `routerCanDeactivate` doesn't work as this is only called if the component is being removed due to the route change, which is not the case in this implementation.

And unfortunately, when looking at the [API for Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html) most of the API's are still missing documentation.

Comment: Are you talking about handling invalid url?

Comment: yes, somewhat, the url is valid, but the last piece is not. e.g. .../details/a/b/c is valid, but .../details/a/b/d is not, the details view handles any router after .../details/*. It will make a request to the backend and if the response is a 404 it should prevent the url change

Comment: oh, seems like renavigate() does exactly what I need, just tried a simple test. (should have tried this before asking the question.

Comment: What do you mean by renavigate()?

Comment: take a look at [@CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html) which is called before changing the route.

Answer (score 2):

### 1.

You can use `@CanActivate` on your child routes, which will be called by    router to decide a route activation hence a route change.

**Usage:**

```ts
import {checkValidUrl} from 'path/to/isUrlValid-service';

@Component({selector: 'control-panel-cmp', template: `<div>Settings: ...</div>`})

@CanActivate(){ //do your checking here and return true/false

    return checkValidUrl.isValid(document.url); 

    // isValid is your function to check the validity
}

class ChildComponent {
}
```

But you'll have to do this on every Child.

---

### 2.

If you want one-time solution, you can create your own `<custom-router-outlet>`

[as Described and Implemented here](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. CanActivate is being called, but the URL is still set to the new utls when I return false. As a quick test I tried to return false if the url is set to .../'test', I would expect the url to revert back to previous url if I  return false, but this doesn't happen.
I have fixed this by keeping track of the URL and call _router.navigateByUrl(prevurl) if the url is invalid. This works, but it would be simpler to use CanActivate.

Comment: that's a limitation that i have also [encountered and overcame partially, see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700848/angular2-how-to-prevent-nullify-history-manipulation-while-implementing-router)

Comment: You can use router.events for checking whether a route was denied access, and then reroute back.